# Как найти вхождение части строки в строке php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Подскажите, как получить кусок строки из базы на основании полной строки. Есть данные VIN авто, допустим JZX906634931. В базе есть поле допустим "kuzov" и там кусок от VIN, в данном случае это JZX90. Вопрос, как получить запись в базе с JZX90 на основание VIN? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: _"Первые три символа содержат информацию о производителе и стране производства автомобиля. Символы с 4 по 8 скрывают данные о модели, типе ее кузова, установленном двигателе и уровне оснащения."_ может вычленить тогда сразу нужную часть, и искать в таблице обычным способом?

Answer (score 1):

Если известно, что полное значение поля `kuzov` есть точная подстрока известного значения VIN, то

```
SELECT table.*
FROM table
WHERE INSTR(@known_VIN, table.kuzov)
```

Если к тому же известно, что эта подстрока идёт с самого начала VIN, то

```
WHERE 1 = INSTR(@known_VIN, table.kuzov)
```

Если же известно, что поле и заданное значение просто должны иметь общую подстроку длины 4 или более, начиная с любого места - задача непростая, и в рамках встроенных функций не решается.

Comment: Решение не соответствует условию. В условии не указано что таблица table существует...

Answer (score -2):

Можете попробовать так:

```
SELECT
    kuzov 
FROM
    table 
WHERE
    vin REGEXP '^[JZX906634931]+$'
```

Comment: Решение не соответствует условию. В условии вообще не сказано, что существует ПОЛЕ таблицы `VIN`.

Comment: @Akina, Возможно это просто пример?

Comment: Возможно. Но раз Вы даёте ответ, а не уточняете задание в комментарии к вопросу - не стоит давать ответ, который этому заданию заведомо не соответствует, верно? А там чётко сказано, что подстрока из известного литерала содержится в поле `kuzov` - значение которого Вы вообще никак не проверяете. К тому же по заданию значение VIN - известно, так какой смысл проверять его регэкспом?